# Why is my Guzzle 6 get() call returning an empty stream?

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, guzzle6

I'm trying to read JSON from an API but for some reason Guzzle returns an empty object. Why? :)

```
    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->request('GET', 'https://etjanster.intra.regionhalland.se/api/v1/getpopularflows/2/json');
    $data = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
    dd($response,$response->getBody(), $response->getBody()->getContents(), $data);
```

dd() prints out the following:

```
Response {#1532 ▼
-reasonPhrase: "OK"
-statusCode: 200
-headers: array:6 [▶]
-headerNames: array:6 [▶]
-protocol: "1.1"
-stream: Stream {#1530 ▶}
}



Stream {#1530 ▼
  -stream: stream resource @16 ▶}
  -size: null
  -seekable: true
  -readable: true
  -writable: true
  -uri: "php://temp"
  -customMetadata: []
}


""


null
```

Comment: Obvious answer: because the API you're calling doesn't return a body. Probably since you're calling an HTTPS endpoint

Comment: @Loek It does, visiting https://etjanster.intra.regionhalland.se/api/v1/getpopularflows/2/json in the browser works just fine

Comment: Hmm, that's actually weird.

Answer (score 4):

I'm fairly sure that with Streams you can only retrieve the data once. So as you are outputting a second call to `$response->getBody()->getContents()` It is returning null.

Instead, try the following:

```
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', 'https://etjanster.intra.regionhalland.se/api/v1/getpopularflows/2/json');
dd(json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents()));
```

And see what your output is...

Comment: I’m currently away from the computer, but shouldn’t that get stored in the $data variable?

Comment: You would have thought so, but there are some caveats with Streams that can make them sometimes confusing and difficult to work with. I think if you also cast it to a string, it should always get the data from the start of the stream. So you could do something like:

```dd(json_decode((string) $response->getBody()->getContents()));```

Comment: Perhaps try changing `$response = $client->request('GET', 'https://etjanster.intra.regionhalland.se/api/v1/getpopularflows/2/json');` to `$response = $client->get('https://etjanster.intra.regionhalland.se/api/v1/getpopularflows/2/json');` and see if that resolves it

Comment: Wow, thanks for this. This worked for me, I was calling $response->getBody()->getContents() more than once, it was behaving as expected with the first call, returning null, the second time.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so I finally found the issue. It was an encoding problem, so the code was actually correct all along. However, Guzzle couldn't handle the `windows-1252` encoding so I did the following that solves my problem but feels like a hack:

```
$response = $client->request('GET', 'https://etjanster.regionhalland.se/api/v1/getpopularflows/5/json', $headers);
$string = $response->getBody()->getContents();
$string = iconv("ISO-8859-1","UTF-8",$string);
$string = json_decode((string) $string, true);
```

Comment: Just wondering, how did you find out? I'd expect a really garbled up decoded json object, not an empty string when there's encoding issues in play.